# Angular 6: How to access API of Electron <webview> Element?

Tags: angular, dom, electron

currently using the awesome [Angular Electron Boilerplate](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron). Let's say I want to access the API of [Electron's webview component](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag).

I have currently created following sample component:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'browserwindow',
    template: '<webview #webview></webview>'
})
export class BrowserwindowComponent implements AfterViewInit {
@ViewChild('webview') webview: any; //which type do I put here?

constructor() { }

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.webview = this.webview.nativeElement;
    this.webview.openDevTools();
}
```

But I get a Type Error: *Cannot read property 'openDevTools' of undefined*.

So what am I doing wrong? Is this approach even a good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct type for a ViewChild is ElementRef (unless it is a more-specific Angular component, but that doesn't appear to be the case here).

```
@ViewChild('webview') webview: ElementRef;
```

According to the Electron documentation, you need to wait for the dom-ready event before accessing the API:

> Note: The webview element must be loaded before using the methods.

```
const webview = document.querySelector('webview')
webview.addEventListener('dom-ready', () => {
    webview.openDevTools()
})
```

... which, therefore, translated into angular-speak in your ngAfterViewInit would be:

```
let webviewNative: WebviewTag = this.webview.nativeElement;
webviewNative.addEventListener('dom-ready', () => {
    webviewNative.openDevTools();
});
```

I don't think you should leave the `@ViewChild` as "any" type and overwrite it like you are, that's asking for trouble because you're losing all the typescript typings by doing that.

If you want to have a class-level reference to the native WebViewTag, declare an additional class variable `webviewNative: WebViewTag = null;` and populate it in ngAfterViewInit with `this.webviewNative = this.webview.nativeElement;`.

Comment: The last code snippet throws an error: 'this.webview.addEventListener is not a function'. However overwriting this.webview with the nativeElement as mentioned above and then calling addEventListener seems to work.

Comment: Never mind! The Electron framework provides the WebviewTag class. Not sure how to convert the dom element to a WebviewTag though. Or maybe the webviewTag is not loaded properly before the method is called. Any tips how to avoid this? Maybe with another angular lifecycle hook?

Comment: Have you tried just making the viewchild be of type WebviewTag?

Comment: It looks to me like the webview tag does not actually expose anything useful, so I don't think that will work. Sorry, I'm out of ideas! Have you considered something like this? https://github.com/ThorstenHans/ngx-electron

Comment: Yes, the webviewTag type defines the opendevtools() method. So defining webviewNative as webviewTag instead of any makes sense to me, also just for the sake of autocompletion. Anyway: Thank you for your help! I understand typescript a little bit more now.

Comment: Great, glad I could help @cyluxx - I've updated the answer to reflect the direct use of the WebviewTag type now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <webview #webview src="https://www.google.com"
        style="display:inline-flex; width:100vw; height:100vh;">
  </webview>
```

---

```
      @ViewChild("webview") webview:ElementRef;
      webviewNative: WebviewTag;
    
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
       
      }
    
      ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.webviewNative = this.webview.nativeElement;
        this.webviewNative.addEventListener('dom-ready', () => {
            this.webviewNative.openDevTools();
        });
      }
    
      back(){
        this.webviewNative.goBack();
      }
    
      next(){
        this.webviewNative.goForward();
      }
```

Comment: please do not post only code , Add a description for more help